# Yen's K shortest paths algoritm - wiki pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode, shortest-path

When analysing pseudocode (from Wiki) of *Yen's K shortest paths algorithm* I noticed that it is possible to find duplicate candidate paths, i.e., a candidate path identical to one already existing either in the candidate stack or among the previously found shortest paths. In short, this can happen because we eliminate from candidates any path which starts with the sequence of nodes identical to the beginning of the last shortest path but don't take account of earlier shortest paths (which could fork from the last one in an earlier node, and thus a candidate can follow it even if it was previously used).

Then I implemented the pseudocode (in PHP) and I was able to find graph examples in which this phenomenon occurs.

If I'm right then it is necessary to supplement the algorithm (pseudocode) with "duplicate check" for any new candidate.

Comment: What is the question here? Guessing, if it is to verify your claim, that would be much easier if the claim got some specifics: the implementation, the graph examples.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Clearly, in [the pseudocode you refer to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm), there is `if (totalPath not in B):`. So yes, you need an implementation of that.

Comment: You are totally right AakashM ! My oversight, thank you, that's clear.   btw I implemented Yen's initially in Python, and then did it in PHP following my Python code (and not Wiki pseudocode) which was of course different "soul"... and I wasn't carefull enough. Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: BTW I made the "initial Python implementation" in January'20. Now I accidentally discovered that the addition of the condition `if (totalPath not in B):` to pseudocode occurred on February 13! So I was not such an onlooker ;)